# Problem with react-native InAppUtils.receiptData

Tags: ios, react-native, in-app-purchase

I use the react-native-in-app-utils (6.0.2) component in my react-native app. After upgrading a lot of components and libraries I'm unable to get the users receiptData using the **InAppUtils.receiptData()** function. Before upgrade this works fine.

After running

```
InAppUtils.receiptData((error, receiptData)=> {
  if(error) {
    Alert.alert('itunes Error', 'Receipt not found.');
  } else {
    // receiptData is undefined/empty and I'am therefore unable to verify the receipe with the users iTunes-account.
  }
});
```

receiptData is undefined/empty and I'am therefore unable to verify the receipe with the users iTunes-account.

Before trying to get the receipt I run **InAppUtils.loadProducts(..) which works fine**, I get all my products.

Any suggestions?

Comment: This is the library that I use https://github.com/chirag04/react-native-in-app-utils

Comment: if anyone experience similar problems, it seems like the problem was related to my testflight accounts (used across several test devices). Creating a new fresh testflight account solved it. InAppUtils.receiptData() and recipe verification now works as expected.